# Setting default filters to order grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, admin-panel

The order grid has to be filtered by default based on the user roles
I have different roles of users .
pakaging team .
invoice team .
For a user belong to packing team the grid should be filtered by default to orders in filtering state.

Answer (score 1):

After apply filter, you can save this. See below picture
[image]

Comment: This filter can be removed by users . But the users can view orders in some specific statuses only depends upon their roles.